# getting duplicate records in Access query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have three tables: The [inventory snapshot] table  shows the name of the product and how many we have on site; the [inbound loads] table shows how many are coming in; the [outbound routes] table lists how many are going out.

I was getting unique values when I only had the first and second table (showing on-hand and 'arriving') but when I added in the third, I began getting multiple records instead of summed records.

#### Purpose of query

I work in a warehouse and I'm trying to isolate pick slots that are 1) low on inventory; 2)have no more product coming in; 3) I'd like to know if there are open orders to ship out any of the remaining product.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [inventory snapshot].locn_brcd,
                [inventory snapshot].description,
                [inventory snapshot].item_name,
                Sum([inventory snapshot].on_hand_qty) AS SumOfON_HAND_QTY,
                Sum([outbound routes].quantity)       AS SumOfQuantity
FROM   [outbound routes]
       RIGHT JOIN ([inbound loads]
                   RIGHT JOIN [inventory snapshot]
                           ON [inbound loads].[wrin number] =
                              [inventory snapshot].item_name)
               ON [outbound routes].[wrin number] =
                  [inventory snapshot].item_name
GROUP  BY [inventory snapshot].locn_brcd,
          [inventory snapshot].description,
          [inventory snapshot].item_name,
          [inbound loads].[quantity to receive]
HAVING ( ( ( Sum([inventory snapshot].on_hand_qty) ) < 10 )
         AND ( ( [inbound loads].[quantity to receive] ) IS NULL ) );
```

Comment: That's a rather complex query.  What is its purpose?

Comment: In your description of the problem, instead of saying "first table, second table, third table," please specify the table names.  We don't know what you mean by "first table, second table, third table."

Comment: I work in a warehouse and I'm trying to isolate pick slots that are 1) low on inventory; 2)have no more product coming in; 3) I'd like to know if there are open orders to ship out any of the remaining product

Comment: OK, let me ask it this way: which table is the "third table" that you added that started causing duplicates?

Comment: I suggest you split the query up into three separate queries. Query1 shows the slots that are low on inventory. Query2 shows the slots that have no more product coming in. Query3 joins Query1 & Query2 to show the open orders to ship out any of the remaining product. Even if you don't make the changes to your database, it would help you identify why you're getting the duplicate rows.

Comment: [Outbound Routes] -- that table has ([outbound routes].quantity) broken up by route. So route 700, 702, 704 could all have deliveries of the same product. I'd like to return the total number of deliveries [ie-quantity] for that product

Comment: @NicholasHunter - Thanks, maybe i should do that to simplify. i'll try it out

Comment: What do you mean *multiple entries*? You mean repeat non-aggregates columns? Before/after data would be helpful to illustrate.

Comment: I was just about to paste some data but I figured out the problem: I'm really only needfor the .item_name but I included the pick slot (.loc_brcd). So the query was returning every location that had that product, not only the slots that we pick from. I removed that field and it works perfectly. It was a silly oversight on my part. Thanks for helping me work through it!

Answer (score 0):

Since you resolved your issue, consider further adjustment of grouping columns. Right now, the `GROUP BY` clause contains one more field than `SELECT` clause, namely: `[inbound loads].[quantity to receive]`.

Typically, in aggregate SQL queries like this one, numeric values like quantity are not grouped but run as aggregated columns. You may have added it to `GROUP BY` in order to use it in `HAVING`. However, non-aggregates can be handled in `WHERE` to filter before aggregation. (Oddly, MS Access tends to move such level filtering in `HAVING` using Query Design.)

Consider below refactored SQL which uses table alias to avoid repetition of long table names. Of course, remove your needless location grouping.

```sql
SELECT s.locn_brcd
     , s.description
     , s.item_name
     , SUM(s.on_hand_qty) AS SumOfON_HAND_QTY
     , SUM(r.quantity) AS SumOfQuantity
FROM   [outbound routes] r
       RIGHT JOIN ([inbound loads] l
                   RIGHT JOIN [inventory snapshot] s
                           ON l.[wrin number] = s.item_name)
               ON r.[wrin number] = s.item_name
WHERE l.[quantity to receive] IS NULL
GROUP  BY s.locn_brcd
        , s.description
        , s.item_name
HAVING SUM(s.on_hand_qty) < 10 ;
```

By the way, the SQL industry tends to use `LEFT JOIN` rather than `RIGHT JOIN` for readability which you may not have control as this query may be output from Query Design. Try equivalent version without nesting `JOIN`s where parentheses is required in Access SQL:

```sql
FROM ([inventory snapshot] s 
LEFT JOIN ([inbound loads] l
   ON l.[wrin number] = s.item_name)
LEFT JOIN [outbound routes] r
   ON r.[wrin number] = s.item_name
```

Comment: The Access query designer seems to favor RIGHT JOIN over LEFT JOIN for some reason.

Comment: @NicholasHunter, actually it is how the user places tables and joins in Query Designer. Had OP started with snapshot table then joined to others, `LEFT JOIN`, would render.